# How to get year in format YY in SQL Server in asp.net C#

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select Year(Creation_Date) 
from Asset_Creation 
where Creation_Date = @Creation_Date
```

I am executing this query where I am getting year as 2013 when supplied today's date. I want the query to return only 13 of 2013. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

```
select right(year(getdate()),2)
select year(getdate()) % 100
```

Comment: It should be noted that the first returns a VARCHAR and the second an INT.  (`select SQL_Variant_Property( right(year(getdate()),2), 'BaseType' )`)

Comment: select year(getdate()) % 100 would return "0" not "00" for years divisible by 100. In case that matters.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky What is the problem with "0"?! If he wants to save the year in int column what would you do (you should cast the char result to int)? It isn't mentioned in question about the return type, and also the performance is another issue. So, you can choose the one you want!

Answer (score 3):

There are more than `2 ways`, 2 of which are:

```
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(Creation_Date),2)
FROM Asset_Creation 
WHERE Creation_Date = @Creation_Date


SELECT SUBSTRING(YEAR(Creation_Date),3,2)
FROM Asset_Creation 
WHERE Creation_Date = @Creation_Date
```